# how to protect against LDAP Injection

Tags: php, ldap, code-injection

We are building an application which utilizes LDAP via php and I got to thinking is there anything you can do with injecting into LDAP and better yet how does one protect against LDAP injections ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When constructing LDAP filters you must ensure that filter values are handled according to [**RFC2254**](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2254.html):

> Any control characters with an ACII
>   code < 32 as well as the characters
>   with special meaning in LDAP filters
>   "*", "(", ")", and "\" (the backslash)
>   are converted into the representation
>   of a backslash followed by two hex
>   digits representing the hexadecimal
>   value of the character.

`Zend_Ldap` for example uses the following routine

```
//[...]
$val = str_replace(array('\\', '*', '(', ')'), array('\5c', '\2a', '\28', '\29'), $val);
for ($i = 0; $i<strlen($val); $i++) {
    $char = substr($val, $i, 1);
    if (ord($char)<32) {
        $hex = dechex(ord($char));
        if (strlen($hex) == 1) $hex = '0' . $hex;
        $val = str_replace($char, '\\' . $hex, $val);
    }
}
//[...]
```

Comment: How would I sanitize the password, since those specials characters are allowed ?

Comment: That's exactly what the above code does... it turns special characters and encodes them.  It's just like URLs, imagine if somebody put a & in a parameter, so you convert it.  Just because the browser/ldap password is smart and tries to fix this error for you, doesn't mean it's still ok to send special characters.

Comment: Tried this solution and it does not work properly.  Had to swap out array of hex characters with: array("\x5c", "\x2a", "\x28", "\x29") to get it to work.

Comment: @KevinRoth: That's not really possible. `array("\x5c", "\x2a", "\x28", "\x29")` is in fact the same as `array('\\', '*', '(', ')')` while RFC2254 requires these characters to be replaced with `'\5c'`, `'\2a'`, `'\28'` and `'\29'` literally.

Comment: I see what you are saying.  Perhaps what I am trying to accomplish is different than the OP.  After I perform an ldap_search, I am doing an ldap_bind for authentication.  When I replace the characters in the user's password, the bind returns false.  Perhaps I should not be replacing characters in the password using this method?  How else can I protect against an injection in the password?  Thanks!

Comment: @KevinRoth: Yes, you shouldn't replace characters in the password used for binding against the LDAP. This escaping just has to happen when you construct LDAP filters for querying to avoid LDAP injections (that's the LDAP equivalent of an SQL injection).

Answer (score 3):

One item to consider is that an LDAP bind with a Username (DN) but no password is considered an anonymous bind.  Therefore should you test to see if the passed credentials can bind via LDAP to validate the user, if they pass a blank password, and you passed it through as is, you could let someone in incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks, this I do understand and is not really an injection.

Comment: @Chris:  Agreed, not truly an injection, but within the same basic problem space.

Comment: After reading this answer, I immediately tested an app we have in development and this particular problem was not caught, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In PHP 5.6+ you should be using the [ldap_escape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-escape.php) function for filter values and RDNs. Such as:

```
// Escaping an LDAP filter for ldap_search ...
$username = ldap_escape($username, null, LDAP_ESCAPE_FILTER);
$filter = "(sAMAccountName=$username)";

// Escaping a DN to be used in an ldap_add, or a rename...
$rdn = ldap_escape('Smith, John', null, LDAP_ESCAPE_DN);
$dn = "cn=$rdn,dc=example,dc=local";
```

Additionally, if you're accepting user input for attribute names in searches you should be validating that it's an acceptable OID or attribute name. You can do that with a function like this:

```
/**
 * Validate an attribute is an OID or a valid string attribute name.
 *
 * @param string
 * @return bool
 */
function isValidAttributeFormat($value)
{
    $matchOid = '/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+?)*?$/';
    $matchDescriptor = '/^\pL([\pL\pN-]+)?$/iu';

    return preg_match($matchOid, $value) 
        || preg_match($matchDescriptor, $value);
}

$attribute = 'sAMAccountName';
$value = 'foo';

if (!isValidAttributeFormat($attribute)) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Invalid attribute name: %s', $attribute));
}

$value = ldap_escape($value, null, LDAP_ESCAPE_FILTER);
$filter = "($attribute=$value)";
```

Answer (score 1):

In most cases it is using a read-only account for LDAP. Since LDAP is poor at writes updates only occur in very small sections of the application where another account can be used.

Even then the query language and the update language are completely separated.

To protect against displaying unwanted information treat all user input as tainted and make sure tainted data is never used before being parsed, cleaned and properly escaped and copied to a clean variable.

Similarly you might consider only picking the data you expect from the response and return that for display.

Comment: "To protect against displaying unwanted information treat all user input as tainted and make sure tainted data is never used before being parsed, cleaned and properly escaped and copied to a clean variable." how would one go about doing this is the question ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function ldap_quote($str) {
    return str_replace(
            array( '\\', ' ', '*', '(', ')' ),
            array( '\\5c', '\\20', '\\2a', '\\28', '\\29' ),
            $str
    );
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.